# Batch file forfiles command to move the files

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I have run the below code to move the files from one folder to another and are 365 days or more old:

```
@echo off
set "src=C:\Notes"   
set "dest=C:\Notes\test"   
for %%F in ("%src%\*") do (  
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ("%%~tF") do (  
    forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c move 0x22%%~fF0x22 0x22%dest%\%%C_%%A0x22 " /d -365  
  )  
)
```

However, I changed the file name and extension like 2017_05,  2017_07, 2018_10 also in attached screenshot.

Can anyone please help to get those files back?

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: Apologies, I am getting you. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Nishant, I've already fixed the code formatting in your question, don't worry about Tiw's comment.

Comment: Unless you confirmed overwriting, the files are still present, just the original names are gone due to your move command. Time to check your backup.

Comment: If you need the extension on the destination use the command modifier `%%~xF`.

Comment: There is also a severe logic flaw in your code.  It is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: Good luck! I guess you'll have to check the file contents and time stamp to determine their original names...

Comment: Oh my. Well, one thing is for sure, I am pretty sure that you learnt from this to rather use `echo` to test your results before performing such a dangerous task.

Comment: if you logged your output, it would be possible to reverse engineer the script.. but suppose not?

Comment: You could pick up a copy of the free, standalone utility, [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), and use that to identify the more common files among them. This can also be used as a command line tool, so if you read the [usage information](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html), you may be able to automate the process from the command line or a batch file too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment...

- Download the Windows executable, [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).
- Unzip the archive to lets say `C:\Users\Nishant\Downloads` and rename the executable file from `exiftool(-k).exe` to to just `exiftool.exe`.
- With your unknown files in `C:\Notes\test` open a Command Prompt window, `cmd.exe`
- Enter the following:

  ```bat
  For %A In ("C:\Notes\test\*") Do @For /F "Tokens=5" %B In ('2^>Nul "C:\Users\Nishant\Downloads\exiftool.exe" -FileTypeExtension "%A"') Do @Ren "%A" "%~nxA.%B"
  ```

Any files for which an extension was found should have been changed to include the extension again. Any which are left will need further investigation.